# Make my background-image in the middle

Tags: html, css

I've a little problem for a website. I want to make the background image centered (in the middle). It's not clear, but here is the image :

[image]

As you can see, there is a little wood image in the background and a div on it. I would like this background-image to be centered (but the div on it with texts shouldn't move). Here is what I made so far - I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work. I need your help !

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid menus" id="our-menus">
    <div class="container menu">
        <div class="menu-content">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Menu</h3>
                <h1>Estival</h1>
                <img src="assets/img/dinner.png" class="img-menu">
                <h2>Entrées</h2>
                <p>Carpaccio de melon charentais</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Moules de bouchot marinière</p>
                <h2>Plats</h2>
                <p>Coeur de boeuf & buffone au basilic</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Brochette d'agneau grillée, jus au thym</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Onglet de boeuf grillé aux échalotes confites</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Filet de cofin rôti aux épices</p>
                <h2>Desserts</h2>
                <p>Coupe glacée manuréva</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Brochette de fraises au chocolat</p>
                <p>ou</p>
                <p>Croustillant à l'orange aux fruits frais, Coulis de framboises</p>
            </div><!-- container -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- container-fluid -->
```

**CSS**

```
.menus{
    background-image: url(../img/wood.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}

.menu{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking or trying to accomplish. According to your CSS, the image is centered. And from the image you provided, it's impossible to tell whether it's centered or not without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

I've added a width to the menu as well as `margin: auto`.
This 'centers' the menu on the screen.

Then, the background-size property for .menus was adjusted to 100% width with any desired height you wish. This gives the impression that the background is smaller than the overlaying menu div.

Example:

```css
.menus{
background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/139306/pexels-photo-139306.jpeg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 500px;
}

.menu{
margin:auto;
width:50%;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid menus" id="our-menus">
            <div class="container menu">
                <div class="menu-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>Menu</h3>
                        <h1>Estival</h1>
                        <img src="assets/img/dinner.png" class="img-menu">
                        <h2>Entrées</h2>
                        <p>Carpaccio de melon charentais</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Moules de bouchot marinière</p>
                        <h2>Plats</h2>
                        <p>Coeur de boeuf & buffone au basilic</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Brochette d'agneau grillée, jus au thym</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Onglet de boeuf grillé aux échalotes confites</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Filet de cofin rôti aux épices</p>
                        <h2>Desserts</h2>
                        <p>Coupe glacée manuréva</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Brochette de fraises au chocolat</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Croustillant à l'orange aux fruits frais, Coulis de framboises</p>
                    </div><!-- container -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
```

Comment: _"I want to make the background image ..."_  None of your solutions would work for the OP

Comment: @Illdapt Thanks for your help btw! ^^ Check this image : https://imgur.com/oAoJBwe That's what I would like ^^

Comment: @ThéoBenoit Check edit? Like so?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the code below.

```css
.menus{
background-image: url('//www.fillmurray.com/500/500');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.menu{
background-color: #F8F8F8;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
max-width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid menus" id="our-menus">
            <div class="container menu">
                <div class="menu-content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>Menu</h3>
                        <h1>Estival</h1>
                        <img src="assets/img/dinner.png" class="img-menu">
                        <h2>Entrées</h2>
                        <p>Carpaccio de melon charentais</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Moules de bouchot marinière</p>
                        <h2>Plats</h2>
                        <p>Coeur de boeuf & buffone au basilic</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Brochette d'agneau grillée, jus au thym</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Onglet de boeuf grillé aux échalotes confites</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Filet de cofin rôti aux épices</p>
                        <h2>Desserts</h2>
                        <p>Coupe glacée manuréva</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Brochette de fraises au chocolat</p>
                        <p>ou</p>
                        <p>Croustillant à l'orange aux fruits frais, Coulis de framboises</p>
                    </div><!-- container -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it. An old and a new way.

**New: (Do this)**

```
.menus{
    background: url(../img/wood.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover auto;
}

.menu{
    background: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

**Old: (Do not do this)**

```
.menus{
    background-image: url(../img/wood.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}

.menu{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

In the old way, you youse multiple lines of code, where you now only need one or two lines. E.g. this: `background: url(../img/wood.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover auto;` instead of all these four steps: `background-image: url(../img/wood.jpg);`, `background-position: center;`, `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, `background-size: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
body { 
    background-image: url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to center the menu div, just use this CSS:

```
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: float does not have a property center.

Comment: Haha, and now it's changed to `text-align: center;`